# Hat ^ operator vs Math.Pow()

Tags: .net, vb.net, pow, exponentiation

Having perused the MSDN documentation for both the [^ (hat) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/exponentiation-operator) and the [Math.Pow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.7) function, I see no explicit difference. Is there one?

There obviously is the difference that one is a function while the other is considered an operator, e.g. this will not work:

```
Public Const x As Double = 3
Public Const y As Double = Math.Pow(2, x) ' Fails because of const-ness
```

But this will:

```
Public Const x As Double = 3
Public Const y As Double = 2^x
```

But is there a difference in how they produce the end result? Does `Math.Pow()` do more safety checking for example? Or is one just some kind of alias for the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to find out is to inspect the IL.  For:

```
Dim x As Double = 3
Dim y As Double = Math.Pow(2, x)
```

The IL is:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 08 40 
IL_000A:  stloc.0     // x
IL_000B:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 
IL_0014:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0015:  call        System.Math.Pow
IL_001A:  stloc.1     // y
```

And for:

```
Dim x As Double = 3
Dim y As Double = 2 ^ x
```

The IL *also* is:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 08 40 
IL_000A:  stloc.0     // x
IL_000B:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 
IL_0014:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0015:  call        System.Math.Pow
IL_001A:  stloc.1     // y
```

IE the compiler has turned the `^` into a call to `Math.Pow` - they're identical at runtime.

Comment: Not sure in VS - personally I just chuck snippets like this into [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRO4F.png).

Comment: Cool, FYI I just found https://dotnetfiddle.net/ that does similar but online, also shows IL :-)