# How to do exponentiation in constant expression?

Tags: c#, math, constants, c#-6.0, exponent

Having used the exponent operator `^` in the initialisation of a VB class's public constant following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804874/hat-operator-vs-math-pow).

```vb
Public Const MaxValue As Double = MaxMantissa * (2 ^ MaxExponent)
```

I am converting the class to C#. however I find that C# does not have the same operator (`^` is still an operator but only as bitwise xor).

`Math.Pow()` is [given as an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034604/is-there-an-exponent-operator-in-c) to the operator, but cannot be used in a constant expression. How then can one initialise a constant with an exponent expression in C#?

(I do not use a value instead of an expression because the values within the expression, also constant, come from different places. `MaxExponent` comes from the base class, `MaxMantissa` is different in each derived class. Furthermore there are multiple constants like this in each derived class such as `MaxPositiveValue`, `MinPositiveValue`, `MinNegativeValue`, `MaxNegativeValue`, etc.)

Comment: C# doesn't have a power operator.

Comment: @Tvde1 Yes, I've said that in the question. I'm asking if there is an alternative method for constant expressions.

Comment: `<<` works in limited cases, other than that you're just out of luck

Comment: @harold good idea, but only works for whole numbers (cant do bit-wise operations on doubles AFAIK)

Comment: Is `readonly` an option? `public static readonly double MaxValue = MaxMantissa * Math.Pow(2.0, MaxExponent);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It turns out that it is. Why I didn't think of that I don't know! Thank you - if you'd like to make that an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since in your particular case you want to raise **2** into `MaxExponent` power

```
2 ** MaxExponent
```

you can put it as a *left shift*, but if and only if `MaxExponent` is a *small positive integer* value:

```
1 << MaxExponent
```

Like this

```
// double: see comments below `1L` stands for `long` and so MaxExponent = [0..63]   
public const double MaxValue = MaxMantissa * (1L << MaxExponent);
```

In *general case* (when `MaxExponent` is an arbitrary `double` value), you can try changing `const` to `readonly`

```
public static readonly double MaxValue = MaxMantissa * Math.Pow(2.0, MaxExponent);
```

Comment: "if and only if `MaxExponent` is a small positive integer value" and what does this mean? This is too vague. Is 100 small? 101? And for what reason for it need to be a small positive integer value?

Comment: @NotAPro: if `2` is of type `int` (`Int32`) *small* `MaxExponent` means in "in `0 .. 31` range", if `2` is of type `long` (`Int64`; in this case we should use `L` suffix: `2L`) *small*  `MaxExponent` is in `0..63` range

Answer (score 3):

You can't, basically (except, as noted, for the trivial case of powers of 2, which can be obtained via the shift operator).

You can hard-code the value and add a comment, or you can use a `static readonly`, but note that `static readonly` doesn't have the same "bake into the call-site" semantics. In *most* cases that doesn't present a problem.